# Null Object in HashSet implementation

Tags: java, hashset

In the Java API, the implementation of HashSet is using an Object as a value for the inside HashMap,

```
   // Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();

public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

but HashMap allows its value is null. I think that's not necessary to fill the value, so why is this needed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the `HashSet` contract specifies that `remove()` return `true` if the specified object existed and was removed.  To do this, it uses the wrapped `HashMap#remove()` which returns the removed value.

If you were to store `null` instead of an object, then the call to `HashMap#remove()` would return `null`, which would be indistinguishable from the result of attempting to remove a non-existent object, and the contract of `HashSet.remove()` could not be fulfilled.

Answer (score 6):

> but HashMap allows its value is null

Why would that matter, when the value is entirely controlled by `HashSet`? That *ensures* that the only value ever associated with a key is `PRESENT`. So if `map.put` returns `null`, that could *only* be because there was previously no entry for that key.

The value is just there because *some* value has to be specified, and if the value *were* specified as `null`, that would be bad - it would make it harder to tell whether there was a value before the call to `add`. If you're going to specify any non-null value, you might as well force it to be the same value all the time - you wouldn't want it to hold up garbage collection, for example.

Now if you're asking why `HashSet` is implemented in terms of `HashMap` rather than being a more efficient implementation which doesn't record a value at all, *that's* a different question, and one I don't have an answer to.

Comment: Hmm, now that I think of it I also am wondering why `HashSet` is implemented in terms of `HashMap`... I would have thought that there would be better ways of doing it.

Comment: My understanding is that they meant to change it...and never got around to it.  To be fair, though, if you just removed the value field from the entries and kept the rest of the implementation constant, you wouldn't actually save any speed or memory, for alignment reasons.  You need a significantly different implementation to start actually beating the HashMap wrapper implementation, and I guess they never did it?

Comment: Does the alignment argument definitely hold for both x86 and x64, with and without compressed oops? If so, I guess that would explain it... it still feels odd though.

Answer (score 0):

In a Java HashMap, a mapping from an object to null is *not* the same as an object not being present in the map at all.  Consider:

```
Object exists = new Object();
map.put(exists, null);
System.out.println(map.contains(exists)) // "true"
System.out.println(map.get(exists)) // "null"
Object notMapped = new Object();
System.out.println(map.contains(notMapped)) // "false"
System.out.println(map.get(notMapped)) // "null"
```

Also, HashMap.put() returns the old value with the key you put, which in your case is null (either because that key wasn't in the map, or its value was null).

Answer (score 0):

With a `Map`, if you call `put(key, null)`, you can't tell the difference between

1. the key already existed, mapping to `null`
2. there was no mapping for that key

Since `HashSet`'s `add` delegates to `HashMap.put`, `PRESENT` is required to fulfil the contract of `Set.add`, which returns `false` if the object already existed in the `Set`:

```
return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one more thing:

As, HashSet add() method works like below:

public boolean add(E e) 
{

```
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

1. Suppose, if PRESENT==null then first time when we add item in HashMap then it return **null** value

   Object exists = new Object();

   ```
           V  value=  map.put(exists,null);
               value will be null here
   ```

   HashSet will return ->    null == null ->> true
2. Second time when we add the same key in hashMap with value as **Null**

   ```
    map.put(exists,null);
   ```

   return null == null ->> true
   It will allows the duplicates in the hashSet.That's why JDK Developers write the PRESENT Object

Answer (score -1):

notice the `==null` part...............