# Why the internal implementation of HashSet creates dummy objects to insert as values in HashMap rather than inserting nulls?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

HashSet is implemented using HashMap and when we add anything say e1 to HashSet, internally it adds (e1,new Object()) in the HashMap if e1 was not present in the set. My question is why they are inserting new Object(), when they could have inserted like (e1,null), which is more optimized approach as no new Objects are created. Is there any downside to inserting nulls here?

Comment: It doesn't add new objects. It adds a single one, which is used as an indicator of the presence of a value in the set. Read the source code.

Comment: In Java 8, they have changed it to 

    private static final Object PRESENT = new Object(); , which is the value.

Comment: there is no performance hit because object is static final so its merely a constant and it will work as dummy value

Comment: you might get your answer here as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829163/null-object-in-hashset-implementation

Comment: @Sandeep The single `PRESENT` object is used as the value for a `HashSet`'s internal `HashMap` at least as far back as Java 5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `HashSet` doesn't add a new `Object` each time a new key is `put` into the map.  It does use an `Object`, but it uses the same `Object` each time.  This value is named `PRESENT` in the `HashSet` source code.

The `add` method calls `put(key, PRESENT)` on the internal `HashMap`.  The `remove` method calls `remove(key)` on the internal `HashMap`, but it must return a `boolean` indicating whether the key was present.  If `null` were stored as the value, then the `HashSet` would need to call `containsKey` first, then `remove`, to determine if the key was present -- additional overhead.  Here, there is only the memory overhead of one `Object`, which is quite minimal.

Answer (score 3):

I just looked at the sourcecode and saw this code

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}

public boolean remove(Object o) {
    return map.remove(o)==PRESENT;
}
```

These would not work if `null` was used instead of `PRESENT`; in each case, an extra step would be required.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. if you give a HashSet object to ConcurrentSkipListSet constructor it cannot contain any null values.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see that **"PRESENT"** is used as value for all elements of set, it is very helpful why?
When you call set.add(-) it return true or false which tell, the element you have added that was present already or not, mean is there any existing element which has been replaced after this add operation. If they will use null as value section of hashMap in put then it is not possible identify that is any values has replace or not because if value not present then also **map.put(-)** method gives null. When they are give dummy **PRESENT** value in **set.add(-)** method then they are getting **PRESENT** values from map.put method which help to confirming that new values has been set and old value is replaced in hashset.